# Can I go with Ubuntu software Center if Ubuntu Software (on 16.04) isn't working properly?

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and noticed that Ubuntu Software (GNOME software) isn't working at all. It seems as if it can't even connect to the internet. When I click on an app icon, it goes to a new screen and stays blank for hours. I can't even see my own installed apps!
1. So, I installed the Ubuntu software center (USC). Is there a disadvantage? Will it be updated with new apps as they come up? 
2. Is there a way to get Ubuntu software working?
(I'm an Ubuntu noob)

Comment: PS: I have seen the other "Ubuntu software not working" questions here, but they're all different issues, like the app page loads but installation doesn't proceed etc. In my case I can't even see my own installed apps.

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu Software"? There's only the Ubuntu Software Center, not Ubuntu Software.

Comment: @StarOS gnome-software calls its self ubuntu software in the window title.

Comment: @MarkKirby Oh, okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I installed the Ubuntu software centre (USC). Is there a
>   disadvantage?"

Yes, it is slow compared to Gnome-software.

> "Will it be updated with new apps as they come up?"

Yes, it uses the same repository for software, the app will update with the repository.

> "Is there a way to get Ubuntu software working?"

First thing to do, as you say it is a new install is

`sudo apt dist-upgrade`

to make sure the packages are up to date, this will fix most issues with Gnome-software.

As Karel already explained installing software-center, I won't repeat it here but it should just work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll go with the old software center then.

Comment: And YES! `sudo apt dist-upgrade` did the job. Ubuntu software is up and running. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you @VP97

Answer (score 2):

Because the default GNOME Software application (Ubuntu Software) and the Ubuntu Software Center do not have the same packages, some people install both applications in order to be able to search for packages in both of them. The Ubuntu Software Center will be discontinued starting in Ubuntu 17.04, but it will still be possible to use Synaptic Package Manager as a replacement app for the Ubuntu Software Center.

To install Ubuntu Software Center alongside Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

To remove Software application and install Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-software
sudo apt install software-center
```

The Ubuntu Software Center will work in Ubuntu 16.04 about the same way as the Software application except for minor differences in the user interface. The available packages in the Ubuntu Software Center will be updated as updates become available by the Software Updater.

In the Dash search for *Software & Updates* and then under the *Ubuntu Software* tab to the right of *Download from* there is a downward black arrow that can be clicked to show a dropdown menu that lets you select the nearest mirror for updating the latest list of software from each archive it knows about. If you haven't already selected the fastest mirror, this can speed up downloading software updates and packages that are waiting to be installed. It sometimes makes a big difference to select the fastest mirror, because the fastest mirror may be able to download at the maximum speed allowed by the terms of your account with your internet service provider.