# Can't Install Apps using Software Center

Tags: apt, gimp

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I was pretty exited about it but when I opened Software Center to download certain apps like GIMP, Python etc. but it showed no results found. I referred to many websites and they show that these apps are available on the Software Center. I have also tried using terminal but it still doesn't work. Please help me!!!

Comment: First of all you need to fully update you system before using the software center. Do so with *sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade* in terminal. Then everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Software centre is not indexed properly / not working properly these days. Don't quote me, I am not an expert. I have never really used it anyway. I use `synaptic package manager` for managing my software packages, why not give that a try and see how you get on.

```
 sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

It will appear in your main menu, run it then enter whatever you like in the search box. Select and install packages.

Comment: -1 Not an answer. Suggestions such as yours should go in the comments.

Comment: I have to disagree. I beleive I have provided an answer. A solution to the issue. Use Synaptic instead. However, I'm not particularly argumentitive. Suggestion, answer, idea, whatever. I am just trying to engage in the question.

Comment: Not being argumentative either but what's the point of installing additional software? The standard one just need updates that can and should be done in terminal or just opening the Updates utility. Besides Synaptic is a dangerous tool for newbies, I've seen too many people borking their system due to incorrect Synaptic use, deleting stuff they shouldn't...

Comment: The point of installing additional software is to have a tool to get the job done. After all, the sofware centre is indeed a tool for installing additional software. I've seen many people kill there system using the software centre, command line apt-get, command line apt, aptitude and synaptic.  I stand by my comment that synaptic (or in fact command line apt-get) is the best way to go.  I personally really don't like the software centre, and so that's my genuine advice. That said, feel free to remove my answer as the issue has been resolved anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Quick <strike>answer</strike> workaround solution:

The default [ GNOME Software ] was just not working for me.

Literally 5 mins ago I installed the [ Ubuntu Software Centre ]

> sudo apt-get install software-center

I am now back to what I am used to in previous Ubuntu versions.

All working fine now for me.

---

Here is a more detailed discussion:

[Can I go with Ubuntu software Center if Ubuntu Software (on 16.04) isn't working properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816197/can-i-go-with-ubuntu-software-center-if-ubuntu-software-on-16-04-isnt-working?rq=1)

Comment: -1 Not an answer. Suggestions such as yours should go in the comments.

Comment: Point taken. I offered a solution - and not an answer. Will be aware of the distinction in future.